# KnockoutJS observable reference to another method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have three files. In the first file there is definition of Data structure or object, where I want to keep some values.

1.File

```
    ....
    function DataTO(){
        ...
        this.object = ko.observable();
        ...
    }
```

Then I have second file, where I have created the DataTO instance and I send this instance to the third file.

2.File

```
    //here is created the object of DataTO instance.
    sendToThirdFile(dataTO().object);
```

In the last file I receive the object parameter, which is attribute called object from DataTO object.

3.File

```
   function(object){
     this.computedValue = ko.observable(value);

     //here I need to set computedValue to object.

     this.object = object;
   }
```

The problem is that, it does not work. Is there any way to change object value always as the computedValue change? So the change would appear in second file?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a fairly indirect answer to your question. but I've had to sort out splitting up a big knockoutjs viewmodel a few times. This is the best solution I've come up with so far.

disclaimer: sorry the syntax is a bit mixed up, many knockout projects can be a bit legacy now days, I've used a mashup of es6 and older code to make this post not take too long.

viewModelLoader.js - loads all the dependancies, creates a global subscribable to pass to each file, after all the dependancies are loaded it bundles all the code up into the main viewmodel.

viewmodelController.js - initalizes your code ready to put into the viewmodel I just like to create this layer so I a fiddle with the load order easily.

fileA, fileB - files to put your code into.

```js
/* 
 viewModelLoader.js  (index.js)
*/

import VMC from './viewmodelController';
import fileA from './fileA';
import fileB from './fileB’;

var viewModelLoader = {
     init: function() {
      var shouter = new ko.subscribable();
       
        VMC.viewmodelController(fileA, fileB);
        ko.applyBindings({
          MyViewModel : new viewmodelController.MyViewModel()
        });
 }
);

viewModelLoader.init();

/* 
 viewmodelController.js
*/
export default {
 viewmodelController: function(fileA, fileB) {
        this.MyViewModel = function() {
           var self = this;

   // do stuff

           fileA.init(self);
           fileB.init(self);

   // do stuff
  }
 }
}

/* 
 fileA.js
*/
export default {
     init: function(self) {
  /* 
   knockout stuff, define some variables / observables
  */
 }
}

/* 
 fileB.js
*/
export default {
     init: function(self) {
  /* 
   knockout stuff, do some stuff the variables 
  */
  
 }
}
```

Here is a older version of this idea using requirejs you could look at to see a working sample https://github.com/digital-pollution/ko-demo